# How to use str_replace_all for multiple numbers replacement?

Tags: r, stringr

I am using the str_replace_all function on my dataframe, but I want to find a way to make it really clean on my data set.

I have multiple numbers value from 1 to 999 in one column, and I want to replace these value by words. I am looking for a way to use large patterns, that would look like :

```
str_replace_all(df$'Column`, "from1to150" = "Team1", "from150to300" = "team2")
```

Could you help me with the "from1to150" part ?

Thank you very much,

Lou

I tried the simple way with single value, but it is not efficient at all and I want this line to be reusable for other projects.

Comment: DO not use `str_replace` but rather use `paste0('Team', (df$Column-1)%/%150)`

Comment: @onyambu, paste as answer? (I would have used `ifelse()` or `case_when()`, but yours seems better (although I think you need to add 1 to the result)

Comment: @BenBolker yes. No need for case when since you cannot list all the cases. eg assume you have 1:12, you need the first 3 be team1, then then next 3 be team2 then the next3 be team3 etc... you can simply do `paste('team', (1:12 - 1) %/%3 + 1)`

Comment: Note that `ifelse` and `case_when` cannot work efficiently here. eg in the example of 1:12 you will have 4 teams, but if you had 1:120 that will be 40 teams!!! @BenBolker

Comment: I agree that the division is best. I read the OP's question too quickly, forgot that they had a max value == 999 (I only looked at their example code).

Comment: Thank you ! Does this solution it also works if I want multiple "teams", around 90, some with large patterns "101to135", others with one or two values ?